# Tomcat maven web project rest application não funcionam netbeans

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, netbeans, navegador-de-internet

Pessoal criei uma aplicação simples para fazer um web service 
fiz da seguinte forma

netbeans
arquivo -> novo projeto -> Maven (aplicação web)
criei uma classe chamada RestApplication

```
package br.com.teste.testeteste.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 *
 * @author Rafael
 */
@ApplicationPath ("/resources")
public class RestApplication extends Application{

}
```

---

Depois criei uma classe Test.java

```
package br.com.teste.testeteste;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 *
 * @author Rafael
 */
@Path ("/test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String primeiro(){
        return"Meu primeiro WebService REST!";
    }
}
```

---

quando executo no glassfish o netbeans abre o navegador e me mostra
http://localhost:8080/testeteste

o meu problema é que quero rodar no tomcat
quando rodo no tomcat ele não abre o browser para mim e quando entro no endereço
http://localhost:8080/testeteste/resources/test
tenho erro 404

enquanto que no glassfish esta funcionando.

alguem pode me ajudar ?

não sei o que está acontecendo com o meu tomcat. quando faço o deploy manual nele tambem não consigo chamar o endereço que tenho 404

Comment: Os dois servidores estão ativos? Se sim, verifique se não está ocorrendo um problema com a concorrência de uso de portas.

Comment: os servidores não os ativo ao mesmo tempo  e não tem concorrência de portas

Comment: Tente fazer o deploy manual e acesse o console de administração do tomcat. Feito isso, entre na opção das aplicações e veja qual é a URL em que a sua aplicação está sendo disponibilizada

Comment: Weslley, fiz o que você sugeriu e quando clico na aplicação após o deploy na parte de aplicações eu tenho o seguinte link  http://localhost:8081/testeteste/ ele abre meu index.html até ai tudo certo porem quando tento acessar o link http://localhost:8081/testeteste/resources/test tenho 404 como retorno. teria alguma sufgestão ?

Comment: Você está usando o TomEE ou o Tomcat padrão? Pode ser que o seu problema esteja justamente aí, uma vez que o Tomcat padrão não vem com suporte nativo para as annotations do JAX-RS, diferente do Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Se você não estiver utilizando a versão TomEE (que tem suporte aos recursos do pacote JAX-RS), vai ser preciso adicionar a dependência a seguir no seu projeto (assumindo que você esteja utilizando o maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```